# TListView automatically appends image in imagelist to first column of my TListView. How do I get rid of this behavior?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-xe8

I am using Embarcadero's C++ Builder XE8. I have a ListView and am adding columns with their items dynamically. I need an imagelist because I want to add an image to the 2nd column aka using (ListItem->SubItemImages[0] = i;)

It seems that by adding this imagelist, C++ Builder by defaults thinks that the primary column also needs an image so it is attaching the 0th element of my image list to all of the items in that column by default. I do not want this to happen. Instead under the column "ID", I just want the ID and not any images. How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot showing whats going on]

My code:

```c++
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  const string firstName[] = {"Snowball", "Scavies", "Tinkerbell", "Fido", "Garfield", "Kobe"};
  const string lastName[] = {"M", "E", "O", "W", "W", "W"};
  TListColumn  *NewColumn;
  TListItem  *ListItem;
  TListView   *ListView = ListView1;

  ListView->SmallImages = ImageList1;

  ListView->ViewStyle = vsReport;
  NewColumn = ListView->Columns->Add();
  NewColumn->Caption = "ID";
  NewColumn = ListView->Columns->Add();
  NewColumn->Caption = "Node";
  NewColumn = ListView->Columns->Add();
  NewColumn->Caption = "First";
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof( firstName ) / sizeof( firstName[0] ); i++)
  {
    char buffer[3];
    itoa(i,buffer,10);
    ListItem = ListView->Items->Add();
    ListItem->Caption = buffer;
    ListItem->SubItems->Add(firstName[i].c_str());
    ListItem->SubItems->Add(lastName[i].c_str());
    ListItem->SubItemImages[0] = i;
    //ListItem->ImageIndex = NULL;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for sharing your story. Do you have a *question*? If so, please [edit] your post to make it clear what you want.

Comment: @RobKennedy Thank you for noticing. Fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add an item to a listview that has an **ImageList** associated it will assume that your intention is to use those images for the items themselves and so each item added will be assigned a default **ImageIndex** of **0** (the first image in the image list).

To remove the image from the item itself all you need to do is replace the default **ImageIndex** of **0** with **-1**, indicating "no image".

```
ListItem->ImageIndex = -1; 
ListItem->SubItemImages[0] = i;
```

As noted in the comments, this deals with not painting the images next to the item captions (Column 0) but the listview will still leave room for those images, even if none are to be painted:

[image: Space left for non-existent images]

There are two ways to avoid that:

1. Do not associate an image list with the listview and use custom drawing to paint any sub-items requiring images.
2. Set the column width of Column 0 to 0 to effectively hide that column and treat the first sub-item as the item caption.

Each approach has trade-offs.

The first requires the added complexity of custom drawing.  The second is more straightforward but means that you will need to enable **RowSelect** behavior on the list view.  Without that, sub-items cannot be used to select items in the list and do not paint with any selection highlight.

It also means that in any event handling etc you have to remember to treat **Subitem[0]** as a special case (the item 'caption'):

```
ListView->RowSelect = true;

// ..

NewColumn = ListView->Columns->Add();
NewColumn->Caption = "Not Used";
NewColumn->Width   = 0;
NewColumn = ListView->Columns->Add();
NewColumn->Caption = "ID";

// ..

// No need to set ListItem->Caption since it is hidden

ListItem->SubItems->Add(buffer);  // subitem[0] = 'the item'
ListItem->SubItems->Add(firstName[i].c_str());
ListItem->SubItems->Add(lastName[i].c_str());
ListItem->SubItemImages[1] = i;
```

There is also a slim chance that some inquisitive user might *resize* **column[0]** and discover your hidden secret.  :)

Comment: This works but now there is just a blank box taking that space where the image would be. Anyway to get rid of this?

Comment: I think again the problem is that since there is an image list associated, the assumption is that your items will have images so space is left for one.  The only way to avoid this I think would be to not have an imagelist associated with the listview and instead use custom drawing to paint your subitem(s).

Comment: Okay. I will try that. Thanks for your input

Comment: You don't need to owner-draw to solve this. In `vsReport` mode, column 0 is used for displaying the `TListItem.ImageIndex` (even if it is -1) when an image list is assigned. So simply add but hide column 0 (set its `Width` to 0), and then add a separate column for the IDs (you will have to use `ListItem->SubItems[0]` instead of `ListItem->Caption` to hold the ID value).

Comment: @Remy a neat idea, as long as you are happy to use **RowSelect = true** since the 1st subitem doesn't behave in *quite* the same way as  `Column[0]`.  In particular, subitems aren't selectable without **RowSelect** and it could complicate the event handling if you then need to treat subitem[0] as a special case subitem (rather than simply item handling vs subitem handling).  But **RowSelect** is usually more than acceptable, to the extent that is should probably be the default, but it isn't and may not *always* be desirable.  :)

Comment: @Remy That works but now the user can still expand the column and see the useless image. Is there no simple way of getting around that?

Comment: @LucaGuarro you can subclass the ListView to intercept [`HDN_BEGINTRACK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775263.aspx) notifications from its header control. Return TRUE for column 0 to prevent resizing. You might also consider having the subclass discard [`LVM_SETCOLUMN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761159.aspx) messages that try to resize the column width directly.

Comment: I will admit that that comment went mostly over my head but it lead me to finding some very old code that I believe you yourself posted [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/3/5/150760.html). I got it to work by just copying the code but since I do not really know what I am doing, it of course makes all columns fixed. How would I prevent resizing for just column 0?

Comment: I do wonder if all this really is simpler than just owner-drawing the sub-item ?  O.o

Answer (score 3):

Is'nt the following what you are looking for?

[image: TItem's caption with no image space]

Then, in the TForm.OnCreate, just set the `ListItem->Indent` property to -1:

```
// in Pascal code
for lListItem in ListView1.Items do
  lListItem.Indent := -1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!